# Why do I get a Error 400 when I want to post a JSON file HTTP REQUEST

Tags: javascript, json, http, object

This is the Code

```html
function loadDoc() {
    var obj = {
        "username": "234zu",
        "subject": "qwertz",
        "content": "qw",
        "created_at": "2018-12-15 22:18:54",
        "updated_at": "2018-12-15 22:18:54"

    }
    var finish = JSON.stringify(obj)

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
   
    xhttp.open("POST", "url", true);
    xhttp.send("finish")
}
```

Ok now when I send the post I get a bad REQUEST
But if I send a Post with post man it goes 
the post looks like 
{
        "id": 844,
        "username": "234zu",
        "subject": "qwertz",
        "content": "qw",
        "created_at": "2018-12-15 22:18:54",
        "updated_at": "2018-12-15 22:18:54"
    }

Comment: maybe Id is required by the server

Comment: Try adding `"id": 244,` to `obj`.

Comment: i have. tried this already but the server generates the id alone

Comment: what is on the server?

Comment: [
    {
        "id": 844,
        "username": "234zu",
        "subject": "qwertz",
        "content": "qw",
        "created_at": "2018-12-15 22:18:54",
        "updated_at": "2018-12-15 22:18:54"
    },
    {
        "id": 848,
        "username": "qq",
        "subject": "qq",
        "content": "qq",
        "created_at": "2019-01-10 08:47:34",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-10 08:47:34"
    },]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the string literal `"finish"` instead of the variable named `finish` having the request body stringified (`var finish = JSON.stringify(obj)`) . try changing to `xhttp.send(finish)`

Also the content type should be mentioned `xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')` before the `send` is called.

Comment: @LeonGreiner did you try with the actual URL? it seems you are using "url" as a string `xhttp.open("POST", "url", true);` ?

Comment: yes it is the actual url put I have deleted the actual url to ask the question

Comment: @LeonGreiner try adding the content type: `xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')` before calling `send`